# How do I configure zsh for completion of partial words, but case-insensitive?

Tags: zsh, zshrc, zsh-completion

Currently I have this in my `~/.zshrc`:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-z}={A-Za-z}' 'r:|[._-]=* r:|=*' 'l:|=* r:|=*'
```

AFAIU `'m:{a-z}={A-Za-z}'` means that I will get case-insensitive tab completion, e.g. `foo` will tab-complete to `Foobar` (if that exists). And `'r:|[._-]=* r:|=*' 'l:|=* r:|=*'` means that I will get matches for later parts of a word, e.g. `bar` will tab-complete to `foobar` (if that exists). But those partial matches are not case-insensitive. So for example `bar` will not tab-complete to `FooBar` (again, in case that exists).

Is there a way to get that working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The matchers in your `matcher-list` are always tried *one at a time,* until one of them returns at least one match. By default, each matcher completely *replaces* the previous one. To instead make the next matcher *include* the previous one, you need to prefix it with `+`:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list \
    'm:{[:lower:]}={[:upper:]}' \
    '+r:|[._-]=* r:|=*' \
    '+l:|=*'
```

See the [`matcher-list` completion style](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-matcher_002dlist_002c-completion-style) doc.

---

> And `'r:|[._-]=* r:|=*' 'l:|=* r:|=*'` means that I will get matches for later parts of a word, e.g. `bar` will tab-complete to `foobar` (if that exists).

Not exactly:

- If `<word>` is the string on the command line that’s being completed, then, by default, Zsh will return completions matching the [glob pattern](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation) `<word>*` — except when `COMPLETE_IN_WORD` is set, which case it will create a completion pattern by inserting the `*` at the cursor position instead.
- `r:|[._-]=*` means “For each occurrence in `<word>` of the empty string followed to the right (`r`) by `.`, `_` or `-`, insert `*` between them (`|`) in the completion pattern.”
- `r:|=*` means “If `<word>` ends on the right with an empty string (which is always true), suffix the completion pattern with `*`.”
- `l:|=*` means “If `<word>` starts on the left with an empty string (always true), prefix the completion pattern with `*`.”
- Multiple subpatterns inserted at the same index in the parent completion pattern are combined with a logical OR.

See the [completion matching control](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#Completion-Matching-Control) docs for a more in-depth explanation.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! `'m:[:lower:]=[:upper:]'` didn't work for me, but adding `+` to my existing matchers worked. :)

Comment: Ah, sorry, that was a typo. It’s fixed now.

Comment: Oh my god, just the line of code I was looking for! Brilliant